# P Wasserstein distance in Python

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, scipy

I know the earth mover's distance is implemented here :

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html

I need to compute the p-Wasserstein distance between two 1d distributions ( or samples from these distributions). The p-WD is given as follows

[image]

Anybody familiar with a Python implementation of the p-Wasserstein distance? anyhelp is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is implemented in the [POT: Python Optimal Transport](https://github.com/rflamary/POT/) package, for samples (or, generally, discrete measures): use [`ot.wasserstein_1d`](https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/all.html#ot.wasserstein_1d).
If you want to do it for weighted samples (or general discrete distributions with finite support), you can provide the `a` and `b` arguments.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if n-d is supported as well in this library ?

Comment: [Yes](https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html); there are various versions with different computation / accuracy tradeoffs depending on the sample size / dimension / etc.